# How can I delete a post?

Tags: discussion, self-delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)

How do you delete a post you don't need anymore? Am I just being blind and can't see the delete button?

Comment: Belongs on meta.

Comment: @Ahsan Valid question but it does not belong here. See the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: And is a duplicate on meta, many times over, I am certain.

Comment: @Oded: then why did you answer the question? Just vote to move, then vote to close as dup.

Comment: @Matt - the answer will be migrated with the question.

Comment: In this particular case, the answer is "You can't, because you have a email/cookie-based account." -- the third reason listed in the FAQ.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You click the `delete` link under the question, above the comments.